# Parallax with jquery Math and CSS percentage values

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, math

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var currentlocation = 350;

$('body').bind('mousewheel', EasyPeasyParallax);

function EasyPeasyParallax() {
   var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
   $('.biglogo_cont').css({ 'opacity': 1-(Math.min(scrollPos/300,1)) });
   $('.biglogo').css({ 'top': currentlocation - (Math.min(scrollPos/1.5,2000)) });
 };

});
```

I've been using the above code for some time to animate css variables based on scroll position but I'm unable to do the same action that I'm doing with .biglogo when using percentage variables. This is absolutely a syntax issue I realize but I've tried the below and can't get it to work.

Any help?

```
$('.biglogo').css({ 'top': currentlocation - (Math.min(scrollPos/1.5,2000)) + % });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close. You are trying to concatenate the `%` modulo, not a percentage string to the result of the subtraction. Wrap the `%` in quotes (`'%'`) and it should help. Also, you can add more specificity to the math (and readability) by wrapping it in parentheses.

```
$('.biglogo').css({ 'top': (currentlocation - Math.min(scrollPos/1.5,2000)) + '%' });
```